# Getting num rows in PEAR DB

Tags: php, pear

The version of DB_DataObject_version is  1.9.6 . Since I have custom query  I am using the method raw query method [PDO Raw Query](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db-dataobject.db-dataobject.query.php). Problem comes when there is no matching records found. otherwise it is working fine .

This is my query

```
$tbl = DB_DataObject::Factory('table_name');
        $tbl->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    $tbl->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $tbl->query("(SELECT * FROM {$tbl->__table} WHERE id = $firstid and id2 = $secondid 
        ORDER BY thirdid DESC)");
```

then I am doing

```
 while($tbl->fetch()){
    ------------------
    -------------------
    my other code
    -----------------------
  }
```

Before doing fetch I like to get the total count of rows.

Comment: Why do you need the count?

Comment: I deleted my answer because i did not see that $tbl wasn't a php PDO object.

Comment: @Your Common Sense because I  need to send response according to that.

Comment: if you need not the number of rows but just to send response, just see if you have any data. The result of "my other code" is apparently an array with data. you can always see if this array contains any data and send appropriate response

Comment: oh ok . Let me check that